# Cannot display font and image properly in Email Template

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have used an email template as a single page html with style (css) embedded to it and I can display all of the styles including font and images properly on the html page. However, the font and image styles cannot be applied to the Outlook messages when I use this template for sending e-mail in my C# application (test version of Windows Service). What I have tried to do so far:

- Added the font file (ttf) to the same directory of my email template as in the example (it is the same directory as html file).
- Embedded image (base64) to the html file as shown below:
- Tried to use font with url as shown below:

  https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

But none of them make any sense and the image sannot be displayed on the e-mail sent by this template. In addition to this, font type is not the same as on the html file (SourceSansPro).

Any idea to embed the font to the html file and display font and image properly on the outlook message created by this template??? Please note that I use *.txt file as template, but the code in it exactly html and can be displayed properly...

Comment: All major webmail email clients such as Gmail, Outlook.com, Yahoo! Mail and Outlook 2007/10/13/16 desktop clients do not support webfonts - https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2012/12/using-web-fonts-in-email/

Comment: you need to do it by inline css.

Comment: @LuisP.A. What about images embedded to html?

Comment: @NegiRox Could you please post an example?

Comment: @ClintEastwood https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2013/02/embedded-images-in-html-email/

Answer (score 1):

Try to insert this code for custom fonts and images in the email template:

```
<style type="text/css">
@media screen {
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Lato Regular'), local('Lato-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/qIIYRU-oROkIk8vfvxw6QvesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff) format('woff');
  }

  ...

  body {
    font-family: "Lato", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Tahoma, Sans-Serif;
  }
</style>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,/*base64-data-string here*/" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, but it does not make any sense. I tried with the same example above by adding my base64-data-string but nothing was changed... Any idea?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/shafayet1991/bab3xw31/ 

I don't know why it is not work on your side. I have tested it before and used this pattern on my laravel project. and it fully worked at my end.

go to my link and see this.Thanks.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. The problem on the mail message, because I can already display the images and font as you did on html pages, but cannot display them on Outlook or Gmail message. Any other idea? Have you tested it by e-mail? Voted+

Answer (score 0):

As for the fonts, there is one single and a very simple solution that works. Just wrap the content inside the deprecated font element!

```
<font face="Verdana">
<!-- content -->
</font>
```

Comment: Actually the main problem is images. Do you have any idea to embed and display images in the mail templates?